# How to get a second statement to run in a method whether the first is true or false

Tags: java

```
 public void setPosition(String aPosition){

    count.getValue();

    if(count.getValue() >= 3){
        count.reset();
    }

    count.click();
    count.getValue();

    if(count.getValue() == 1) {
        aPosition = firstP;
    } else if(count.getValue() == 2) {
        aPosition = secondP;
    } else if(count.getValue() == 3) {
        aPosition = thirdP;
    }
}
```

I have to set a position for a lock three times. Using the counter i will set the value three times by calling the method three times. But i don't know how to get the second statement (the second if) to run even if the first "if" is true or false. Should i use a boolean operator here or what method am i forgetting?? I tried looking for an answer but it always shows me people asking about boolean operators like && or ||.

Edit: For clarification, i want (this is second statement) `if(count.getValue() == 1) {
            aPosition = firstP;
        } else if(count.getValue() == 2) {
            aPosition = secondP;
        } else if(count.getValue() == 3) {
            aPosition = thirdP;
        }`

to run even if (This is first statement) `if(count.getValue() >= 3){
            count.reset();
        }`

if false. This is because when i call the method in my tester class it will run that one first, which it will be false for the first 3 times i call it. The value will only reset when i call it a 4th time which then it will be true because value>=3. But in this setup, it only runs the second statement if the first statement is true.

Comment: Remove the `else`? Although I'm not sure how that would change anything...

Comment: Just FYI, assigning a value to the argument will have absolutely no effect.

Comment: If `count.getValue()` returns 1, then your second statement, `count.getValue() == 2` cannot be true - so there's no point in even checking. So what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: @nos I edited it for better clarification. But when i first call the this method in my tester class it will have a value of 1. Then when the user inputs a letter that will be assigned to firstP. Then when i call it a second time it will assign another value the user inputs into secondP since value will = 2. Then so on. When i call it a fourth time it's suppose to reset the value back to 0 so when i call it three times again it will assign the new values. FYI this lock has 3 combinations of a single letter each. "FIU" or "ATY", etc....

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to get the second statement (the second if) to run even if the first "if" is true or false

So instead of using `else if` you want to just have it as a separate `if` statement:

```
if(count.getValue() == 1){
    aPosition = firstP;
}

if(count.getValue() == 2) {
    aPosition = secondP;
} else if(count.getValue() == 3) {
    aPosition = thirdP;
}
```